# Changing summation indices

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, summation

How does one prove the following result, where $x$ is a three-parameter function defined on $\mathbb Z^3$? $$ \Sigma_{\ell=1}^{P}\Sigma^{\ell-1}_{i=0}  x(\ell,i,\ell-i) \quad = \quad \Sigma^{P}_{j=1}\Sigma^{P-j}_{i=0} x(i+j,i,j)$$

So far, I've realised three things:

$\\$
(1) $\Sigma_{\ell=1}^{P}\Sigma^{\ell-1}_{i=0} 1 = p(p-1)/2 =\Sigma^{P}_{j=1}\Sigma^{P-j}_{i=0} 1 \\$

(2) The regions $\{0\leq i \leq \ell -1 \leq p -1, \ell>1\}$ and $\{0\leq j-1 \leq i+j -1 \leq p-1\}$, both in $\mathbb Z^2$, describe isosceles triangles (respectively, bottom-left triangle and bottom-right triangle of square with sides $\overline{(1,1)(1,p)}$ and $\overline{(1,1)(p-1,1)}\\$).

(3) It is tempting to quick-and-dirtily substitute $\ell = i+j$, and one does get

$$ \Sigma_{\ell=1}^{P}\Sigma^{\ell-1}_{i=0}  x(\ell,i,\ell-i) \quad = \quad\Sigma_{j+i=1}^{P}\Sigma^{j+i-1}_{i=0}  x(j+i,i,j) \quad$$

which gives the right indices for the arguments of $x$, but the upper bound on the second summation is nonsensical (what is a sum ranging from $i=0$ up to $i=j+i-1$?)

PS: This appears in "Differential Eq. Driven by Rough Signal", Revista Matemática Iberoeamicana, Lyons, 1998.

Comment: The only way that I know of to attack such problems is two-fold.  First, I experiment with small values for $P$ (e.g. $P = 5$), forming a two dimensional chart, and actually listing all LHS terms and all RHS terms.  I do this to try to stretch my intuition around what the assertion represents.  Then, I try to craft a generic visual (two-dimensional chart) proof, that the assertion is true, applying the proof to the specific value of $P$ (e.g. $P = 5$).  Then, I try to prove, through a generic two dimensional chart, that the LHS and RHS summations have terms which perfectly match up.

Comment: What I do **not** do, for such a problem, is to initially strive to replace elbow grease with elegance.  In my opinion, elegance in such a setting comes only after a reasonably deep fluency with this type of problem.  For me, such fluency is developed only by working on many, many exercises on (virtually) the same summation-equivalence issue.  Nested summation re-indexing is (for me) no walk in the park, because I am not fluent in that area.

Comment: In the initial summation $\sum_{l=1}^P\sum_{i=0}^{l-1}x(l,i,l-i)$,
the upper bound on the $i$ sum takes values $0, 1, 2, \dotsc, P-1$, i.e. $l-1$ for $l = 1, 2, \dotsc, P$. We can reverse it and express it as a function of $l$: $P-1, P-2, P-3, \dotsc, 0$ is given by $P-l$ for $l = 1, 2, \dotsc, P$. The sum then becomes $\sum_{l=1}^P\sum_{i=0}^{P-l}x(l,i,l-i)$.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff thanks very much, any insight on how to go from where you left into the expression with the $j$'s?

Comment: I see now that your equation can't be true as stated. Take $x(a,b,c) = a$. Then using my form of the summation we get $\sum_{l=1}^P\sum_{i=0}^{P-l} l$ for the LHS, but the RHS of your equation is $\sum_{l=1}^P\sum_{i=0}^{P-l}(l+i)$ which is clearly always a greater quantity (except in the case of an empty sum with $P=0$). Are you missing a condition on $x(a,b,c)$?

Comment: I agree, this is patently false without further assumptions on x. Take $p=4$, then $x(7,3,4)$ comes up on the RHS but clearly not on the LHS

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff, I am afraid your change of order argument doesn't work since it yields negative values for the third argument of $x$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4484373/changing-index-of-a-summation?noredirect=1#comment9404589_4484373

Comment: Ahhh, you're right. We have to keep the same $l$ associated with each $i$-summation. It should be $\sum_{l=1}^P\sum_{i=0}^{P-l}x(P-l+1, i, P-l-i+1)$.

Comment: Addition is commutative:  $\sum_{j=1}^P f(j) = f(1)+f(2) + ..... + f(p) = f(p) + f(p-1)+ ...+f(1) = \sum_{k=1}^p f(P-(k-1))$.  That's really all there is to it.

Comment: @fleablood if you see it so simply, I’d be grateful of you sharing a few more details in an answer or a comment

Comment: I personally don’t think that reversing things in a double summations is that simple for one, and then proving that your reversed sum is equal to the sum witb the changed indices is hard for two (see the below answer by @epi163sqrt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To restate your question, you are asking why
$$
\sum_{(\ell,i,j)\in A}x(\ell,i,j)=\sum_{(\ell,i,j)\in B}x(\ell,i,j),
$$
where
$$
A=\{(\ell,i,\ell-i)\in \mathbb Z^3\mid 1\le \ell \le P,0\le i\le \ell-1\}\\
B=\{(i+j,i,j)\in \mathbb Z^3\mid 1\le j \le P,0\le i\le P-j\}
$$
The reason is that $A=B$; both summations are over the same set of integer vectors, so they are equal.

To prove $A=B$, you just need to show every vector in $A$ is also in $B$, and that every vector in $B$ is also in $A$. I will help you with the first part.

Let $(\ell,i,\ell-i)$ be a vector in $A$. By definition of $A$, we know $$1\le \ell \le P\quad\text{and}\quad 0\le i\le \ell-1$$Define $j:=\ell-i$. Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\begin{array}{l}
j=\ell-i\le P-i\le P,\\
j=\ell-i\ge\ell-(\ell-1)=1
\end{array} 
&\implies 1\le j \le P \tag1\\\\
i+j=\ell\le P
&\implies i\le P-j\tag2
\end{align}
$$
We have shown that $(i,j)$ satisfies all of the conditions defining $B$. This means that $(i+j,i,j)=(\ell,i,\ell-i)$ is an element of $B$, so $A\subseteq B$

The same type of reasoning proves $B\subseteq A$. I encourage you to write out the details yourself.

---

The above is the rigorous proof of equality. Here is the intuition, and the way I think about these problems when I see them in the wild.

Let's say you start with $\sum_{\ell=1}^P\sum_{i=0}^{\ell-1} x(\ell,i,\ell-i)$, and you want to transform in into $$\sum_{j=?}^?\sum_{i=?}^?x(i+j,i,j),$$but you do not know what the bounds are. We proceed the same way you do when switching the order of summation for multivariable integrals. First, figure out the bounds on the variables for the original sum. The outer sum goes $\ell=1$ to $P$, and the inner from $i=0$ to $\ell-1$, so we get
$$
0\le i\le \ell-1,\qquad 1\le \ell \le P
$$
Now, to get from a sum of $x(\ell,i,\ell-i)$ to $x(i+j,i,j)$, it is clear we need to let $j=\ell-i$. Since $j$ is the outer summation variable for the new sum, we need to figure out the bounds on $j$ implies by those on $i$ and $\ell$. See $(1)$ for what this work looks like. Since the conclusion is $1\le j \le P$, we have deduced the outer limits are $1$ to $P$. Similarly, proceeding as in $(2)$, you can deduce the inner limits are $0$ to $P-j$.

Comment: That’s a very clean way to show it. Thank you. Is there any intuition that can help me “guess” this should be right from looking at it though? Eg, realising that we are reversing the second summation order, and then changing the argument we are fixing with the first sum (the first vs the last)

Comment: I tried my best to add some intuition to the edit.

Answer (score 1):

The following might also be sometimes useful. At first we bring lower and upper indices of the sums in similar form to ease comparison. Then we check if we can derive from it the wanted equality.

> **Left-hand side and right-hand side:**
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{l=1}^{P}\sum_{i=0}^{l-1}x(l,i,l-i)
> &=\sum_{l=0}^{P-1}\sum_{i=0}^lx(l+1,i,l+1-i)\tag{1.1}\\
> &=\sum_{\color{blue}{0\leq i\leq l\leq P-1}}x(l+1,i,l+1-i)\tag{1.2}\\
> \\
> \sum_{j=1}^P\sum_{i=0}^{P-j}x(i+j,i,j)
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{P-1}\sum_{i=0}^{P-j-1}x(i+j+1,i,j+1)\tag{2.1}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{P-1}\sum_{i=0}^jx(i+P-j,i,P-j)\tag{2.2}\\
> &=\sum_{\color{blue}{0\leq i\leq j\leq P-1}}x(i+P-j,i,P-j)\tag{2.3}
> \end{align*}
> **Analysis:**
>
> - The index regions in (1.2) and (2.3) show that $0\leq i\leq P-1$ in both cases indicating a mapping $i\to i$ which is consistent with the middle argument in $x(\cdot,\Box,\cdot)$.
> - We have $i\leq l\leq P-1$ at the LHS and $i\leq j\leq P-1$ at the RHS. So, both indices $l$ and $j$ are going from $i$ to $P-1$.
> - The leftmost argument in $x(\Box,\cdot,\cdot)$ indicates a mapping
>   \begin{align*}
>   l\to i+P-j-1\qquad\text{resp.}\qquad j\to i-l+P-1\tag{3}
>   \end{align*}
>   which coincides with the rightmost argument in $x(\cdot,\cdot,\Box)$ as well!
> - Finally we need to show that $l$ and $j$ are bijectively mapped via (3). Since we have according to (3)
>   \begin{align*}
>   \begin{array}{l|cccccc}
>   l&i,&i+1,&i+2,&\ldots,&P-2,&P-1\\
>   j&P-1,&P-2,&P-3,&\ldots,&i+1,&i
>   \end{array}
>   \end{align*}
>   just a reverse ordering of ${i,i+1,\ldots,P-1}$ when using $l$ resp. $j$.
>
> **Conclusion:** The equality of the sums (1.2) and (2.3) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1.1) we shift the index $l$ to start with $l=0$ to conveniently write the index region als inequality chain in (1.2).
- In (2.1) we shift the index $j$ to start with $j=0$.
- In (2.2) we change the order summation of the outer sum $j \to P-1-j$.
- In (2.3) we also write the index region as inequality chain to ease comparison with (1.2).